# JavaFX: Scroll pane not fitting parent

Tags: java, javafx, layout

I would like to create following scene:

```
+-----------------------------------------------+
|ROOT (=BorderPane)                             |
|                                               |
| +-------------------------------------------+ |
| |TOOL BAR                                   | |
| |(north)                                    | |
| +-------------------------------------------+ |
|                                               |
| +-------------------------------------------+ |
| |MyConfigurationComponent extends BorderPane| |
| |(center)                                   | |
| |  +-------------------------+  +---------+ | |
| |  |ScrollPane               |  |         | | |
| |  |(center)                 |  |         | | |
| |  | +---------------------+ |  |         | | |
| |  | |                     | |  |         | | |
| |  | |                     | |  |  SIDE   | | |
| |  | |       CANVAS        | |  |  PANE   | | |
| |  | |                     | |  | (right) | | |
| |  | |                     | |  |         | | |
| |  | |                     | |  |         | | |
| |  | +---------------------+ |  |         | | |
| |  |                         |  |         | | |
| |  +-------------------------+  +---------+ | |
| |                                           | |
| +-------------------------------------------+ |
|                                               |
+-----------------------------------------------+
```

### Expectation

I would like to make the `ScrollPane` as big as possible. That means that `ScrollPane` should grow and fill entire area, whatever the size of scene is.

Since both the `TOOL BAR` and `SIDE PANE` have fixed (preferred) width and height, I thought that the `ScrollPane` will stretch and fill the whole remaining area.

### Actual behavior

But it doesn't. The `ScrollPane` somehow magically sets its minimum size to something about 40x40. The height is stretched to match height of `SIDE PANEL`, but the width is still the same and nothing seems to be able to change it.

In fact, the only one thing, which makes the `ScrollPane` bigger was to explicitly set minWidth to some value (i.e. 400). But this does not solve issue about the `ScrollPane`'s auto resisize.

When I set background color to `MyConfigurationComponent`, I can see that background color fills whole area as expected (so the problem is not with `MyConfigurationComponent`). It looks like its center child (`ScrollPane`) is rendered as left, its right child (`SIDE PANEL`) as center, because all the remaining area on the right side remains blank (but with the background, so it is still `MyConfigurationComponent`!).

### What have I tried

- set `min`, `pref`, and `max` sizes of `ScrollPane` to particular values
- bind prefered size to parent's size
- set `fitToWidth` and `fitToHeight` to true
- wrap `ScrollPane` with `AnchorPane` with anchor to all four sides
- wrap `ScrollPane` with VBox and set priority to allways

### Current workaround

Bind the width of `MyConfigurationComponent` minus width of `SIDE PANEL` to `ScrollPane`. Wrong in many ways.

### Code

#### ROOT.fxml

```
<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="cz.upol.fapapp.cfa.gui.frame.FxCFAConfigFrameController">
   <top>
            <ToolBar>
                <Button text="Some button" />
            </ToolBar>
   </top>
   <center>
      <MyConfigurationComponent fx:id="configComp" />
   </center> 
</BorderPane>
```

#### MyConfigurationComponent.fxml

```
<BorderPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <center>
        <ScrollPane fx:id="scrollPane">
            <content>
                <Canvas width="2000" height="2000" />
            </content>
        </ScrollPane>
    </center>
    <right>
        <VBox prefWidth="100.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER_RIGHT">
            <children>
                <Label text="Colors" />
                <ComboBox fx:id="cmbColors" prefWidth="100.0" />    
                <!-- ... -->
                <Separator prefHeight="15.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Action 1" />
                <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Action 2" />
            </children>
        </VBox>
    </right>
</BorderPane>
```

### Questions

- `BorderPane`'s center extends its size to fill content, isn't it?
- Can this be somehow caused by `BorderPane` inside of `BorderPane`?
- Is there better solution than 'my workaround'?

Comment: Is it possible to use `AnchorPane` instead of `BorderPane` as the parent to `MyConfigurationComponent`? That way you could use the FXML `AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="100.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0"` in the opening `ScrollPane` tag, where .rightAnchor is assigned to the width of your "Side Panel"

Comment: From the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/BorderPane.html): *The top and bottom children will be resized to their preferred heights and extend the width of the border pane. The left and right children will be resized to their preferred widths and extend the length between the top and bottom nodes. And the center node will be resized to fill the available space in the middle.* `BorderPane` isn't the right layout for the expected behavior. Use a `HBox` and set `hgrow` for the `BorderPane` and the side pane to `ALWAYS` and `NEVER` respectively.

Comment: I copied and pasted your FXML exactly as it is (doing the minimum to make it so I could run it; i.e. I replaced `<MyConfigurationComponent>` with `<fx:include>`, removed the controller, etc), and it worked as expected: the scroll pane filled the space not occupied by the toolbar or the `VBox` on the right side. So whatever is causing it to fail to work the way you want is somewhere else in your code. Expand the code in the question to a [MCVE].

Comment: I suspect the problem lies in the way you are implementing the `MyConfigurationComponent` class. Normally if you use your own node subclass, and performing the layout for that in FXML, you would use [this technique](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#custom_components). But since you don't have `<fx:root>` in the FXML for `MyConfigurationComponent`, you are clearly doing something else. My guess is that is where the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

You can put this in your code, inside of the start method:

```
stage.widthProperty().addListener(event -> {
    scrollPane.setPrefWidth(stage.getWidth());
});

stage.heightProperty().addListener(event -> {
    scrollPane.setPrefHeight(stage.getHeight());
});
```

If that doesn't work, I'd recommend setting the BorderPane's width and height to the dimensions of the stage, too:

```
stage.widthProperty().addListener(event -> {
    scrollPane.setPrefWidth(stage.getWidth());
    borderPane.setPrefWidth(stage.getWidth());
});

stage.heightProperty().addListener(event -> {
    scrollPane.setPrefHeight(stage.getHeight());
    borderPane.setPrefHeight(stage.getHeight());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner answer would be to use [ScrollPane.setFitToWidth(boolean value)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ScrollPane.html#setFitToWidth-boolean-) and [ScrollPane.setFitToHeight(boolean value)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ScrollPane.html#setFitToHeight-boolean-).